# How to build a source package glibc-source for arm architecture on x86 machine

Tags: arm, glibc, arm64

I am building a glibc-source for `arm` architecture but I am getting the following issue.

I have run the following commands:

```
apt-get source glibc-source
sudo apt-get build-dep glibc-source
```

Changed the file `control.mk` to target `arm`:

```
vi ../debian/rules.d/control.mk 
libc_archs :=arm
```

`sudo TARGET=arm dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b -d -rfakeroot`

After running the above command, I am getting the following error (even though I mentioned Target as `arm`, still it is building for `amd64`):

```
make[3]: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/systebui/glibc-2.5/glibc-2.23/gmon'
Makefile:230: recipe for target 'gmon/subdir_lib' failed
make[2]: *** [gmon/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/systebui/glibc-2.5/glibc-2.23'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/systebui/glibc-2.5/glibc-2.23/build-tree/amd64-libc'
debian/rules.d/build.mk:105: recipe for target '/home/systebui/glibc-2.5/glibc-2.23/stamp-dir/build_libc' failed
make: *** [/home/systebui/glibc-2.5/glibc-2.23/stamp-dir/build_libc] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

If I am not changing the `control.mk` file then it successfully runs without errors, but for `x86,i386` and not for `arm` and `arm64` architectures.

Can anyone please let me know how to set the Target for Building a Glibc for `arm` and `arm64`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are armhf/arm64 packages for libc in Ubuntu already. Why do you need to rebuild it? The packages are built directly on ARM hardware, and not cross-compiled, so you won't be able to simply cross-compile in the way that you are trying to do. I don't think 'arm' is a valid arch definition for glibc either, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I build i386 and amd64 packages on my amd64 laptop using debuild](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595226/how-can-i-build-i386-and-amd64-packages-on-my-amd64-laptop-using-debuild)

Comment: Concerning the only answer to the linked question: the chroot option won't work in your case but the other options remain, including the given `debuild` flags.

Comment: i am building glibc-source on my x86 machine i need to build it for arm architecture.